# TADOConnection + {Oracle in XEClient}

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток.
Написала тестовую програмку. На форме одна кнопка, которая делает

```
c:=TADOConnection.Create(nil);    
//c.ConnectionString:='DRIVER={Oracle in XEClient}; UID=user; PWD=psw; SERVER=AlexXE; DBQ=AlexXE';
c.ConnectionString:='DRIVER={Oracle in OraHome92}; UID=user; PWD=psw; SERVER=ORA92;DBQ=ORA92';
c.Connected:=true;
```

Соединение устанавливается с любой из 2-х ConnectionString. Но при выгрузке приложения если указана закомментированная строка подключения выдает access violation. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте при закрытий формы (onFormClose,onFormQueryClose)

освободить АДО :

<code>c.disconnect;
c.free;</code>

Comment: Пробовала, но проблема в том, что глюк нестабильный. Чаще всего ловится с закомментированным драйвером. При подключении к MS SQL или SQLExpress не возникает вовсе. Забыла упонять, что в любом случае подключаемся на удаленную машину, а AlexXE - виртуалка.